# Azure Formrecognizer - how to improve input image quality by performing preprocessing?

Tags: azure, ocr, image-preprocessing, azure-form-recognizer

Does the Azure FormRecognizer by default does any preprocessing to the file to improve the accuracy of recognition by the OCR Engine. Just out of curiosity I performed preprocessing(like- **binarisation** **cv2.adaptiveThreshold**, Denoised the image using **cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising** and **cv2.medianBlur**, performed Thinning as the image contains handwritten text and finally performed skew correction on the images before posting a request to azure. I sent two request one with an original image and the preprocessed image to my suprise the original image results were way-better compared to the preprocessed image. What could be the reason for this..does Azure formrecognizer do any preprocessing ? Any ideas on where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer does all the processing, no need to pre-process images before sending them to Form Recognizer you can send the image as is and Form Recognizer will extract the data from it.